# React Typescript route file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to create `routes.ts` file in React (typescript) version with following code (sample in JS Version)

```
routes = [
  {
    path: 'app', component: isLoggedIn ? <HomeComponent /> : <Navigate to="/login" />, 
    children: [
      { path: '', component: <Navigate to="/dashboard" /> },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: <DashboardComponent /> },
      { path: 'other', component: <OtherComponent /> },
    ] 
  },
  { path: 'login', component: <LoginComponent />  },
  { path: 'register', component: <RegisterComponent />  },
  { path: '**', component: <NotFoundComponent />  },
]
```

in `App.tsx` it should be like this, reference of JS version

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    {routes.map(r => {
      ...//logic
    })}
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

This is written in very brief just to explain the requirement. PS: The JS version works very well with this logic, but TS conversion is difficult and unavailable currently in docs and forums

Comment: What is the issue you have with the code? Can you clarify? Also, why not use a more conventional RRDv6 routes config instead of rolling your own implementation?

Comment: Something like `r => <Route path={r.path} component={r.component}>{r.children}</Route>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own route rendering logic I'd suggest converting the `routes` config object to a format that lends itself to working with `react-router-dom` more easily. Not much needs to change, basically just switch the components from a `component` prop to the `element` prop.

```
import { RouteObject } from "react-router-dom";

...

const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    path: "app",
    element: isLoggedIn ? <HomeComponent /> : <Navigate to="/login" />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Navigate to="dashboard" /> },
      { path: "dashboard", element: <DashboardComponent /> },
      { path: "other", element: <OtherComponent /> }
    ]
  },
  { path: "login", element: <LoginComponent /> },
  { path: "register", element: <RegisterComponent /> },
  { path: "*", element: <NotFoundComponent /> }
];
```

Import and use the `createBrowserRouter` (*any of the data routers, see [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) for details*) and the [`RouterProvider`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider).

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";

...

const router = createBrowserRouter(routes);

...

<RouterProvider router={router} />
```

Typescript demo

[image: Edit react-typescript-route-file]

If you aren't quite ready to make the jump to the Data routers then keep the `BrowserRouter` and use the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) hook instead.

```
import {
  Navigate,
  RouteObject,
  useRoutes
} from "react-router-dom";

...

const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  { path: "/", element: <Navigate to="app" /> },
  {
    path: "app",
    element: isLoggedIn ? <HomeComponent /> : <Navigate to="/login" />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Navigate to="dashboard" /> },
      { path: "dashboard", element: <DashboardComponent /> },
      { path: "other", element: <OtherComponent /> }
    ]
  },
  { path: "login", element: <LoginComponent /> },
  { path: "register", element: <RegisterComponent /> },
  { path: "*", element: <NotFoundComponent /> }
];

const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);

...

return (
  ...
  {appRoutes}
  ...
);
```

[image: Edit react-typescript-route-file (forked)]

Comment: error : Conversion of type 'RegExp' to type 'Admin' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
Error 2 : 'Navigate' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Navigate'?

Comment: @YashSoni What is that? Where is that error being generated from?

Comment: my file was ending with extension .ts but it should be .tsx , Your solution worked ,thanks